# Cant split a string using php

Tags: php

I can't split the string  `C:\fakepath\one.xls`  using the character `\`. It shows an error.

My code is:

```
$file=C:\fakepath\one.xls;
$file1=explode("\",$file);
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Is C:\fakepath\one.xls-your string?

Comment: Php code color is changed,like that of the case when one double quote is not colsed

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php  please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$file = 'C:\fakepath\one.xls';
$file = explode("\\",$file);
print_r($file);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => C: [1] => fakepath [2] => one.xls )
```

Comment: string is 'C:\fakepath\one.xls'.these value is in ajax page.  $file=$_POST['file']; . $file contain C:\fakepath\one.xls.

Comment: 1 up for that escape part.. but the file name is coming from some other page. So `\` needed to be appended manually.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the string in quotes, and the backslashes need to be escaped:

```
$file='C:\\fakepath\\one.xls';
$file1=explode("\\",$file);
```

Comment: The \ also have to be escaped in the explode statement!

Comment: wut wut wut? Why does the `\` need to be escaped in this particular sentence? There is no quote following it, now is there?